# how to get the value from a single item DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame which consists of a single column, and single entry. is there a more direct way of getting that single value other than:

```
df.values.item(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df.iat[0, 0]
```